# How do I install a point release of Postgres 10, like Postgres 10.2?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, postgresql

It appears to be easy to install the latest point release of Postgres 10, which, at the time of writing appears to be Postgres 10.3. However, I want to install Postgres 10.2, which I cannot seem to figure out how to do.

I'm on Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and am following these instructions: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

I've added this repository: `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`
I've imported the signing key:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
  sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I can install Postgres 10 like so:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```

which fetches version 10.3:

```
Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main postgresql-10 amd64 10.3-1.pgdg14.04+1 [4,793 kB]
```

However, to install an old version, I thought it would just be a matter of specifying the version of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10=10.2-1.pgdg14.04+1
```

But I just get an error:

```
Version '10.2-1.pgdg14.04+1' for 'postgresql-10' was not found
```

So that version doesn't appear to be published. And you can't specify a different package like you could back with 9.x. To install various versions of PG 9.x, you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

But you can'd do that with 10.x:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10.2
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-10.2'
```

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: If their repository doesn't keep it, you might want to try some other repository

Comment: Thanks @muru. Do you know how I go about finding other said repository for archives like that?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 10, PostgreSQL has changed its versioning scheme as explained in https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

> Beginning with version 10, a major release is indicated by increasing
>   the first part of the version, e.g. 10 to 11. Before version 10, a
>   major release was indicated by increasing either the first or second
>   part of the version number, e.g. 9.5 to 9.6.

This is why there is a `postgresql-9.6` package, but no `postgresql-10.2` package: it's `postgresql-10`. The versions `10.0` through `10.2` contain bugs that have been fixed in `10.3` so there is no compelling reason for APT repositories to keep them around.

Comment: Thanks. That does explain why Postgres doesn't archive those versions. However, we need access to legacy versions, at least temporarily, because we want to use the exact same version of Postgres that our provider does. As soon as our provider upgrades, we can upgrade our dev environment, but before that, we'll need to install an older version.